# RxJS and-thenDo-when example

Tags: operators, rxjs5

Dou you have a working example for me ? Which use-case can/should apply this pattern? The information here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/and-then-when.html#collapseRxJS is very short.

Comment: This question entirely depends on the availability of the linked resource. If it goes away, or the site is down, SO users will have no context to understand what your question is. Please describe the problem you're having in detail as part of this post and then ask a specific question about it. Voting for close.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the RxJS 4 docs:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/thendo.md

```
var selector = function (x, y) { return x + ", " + y; };

var source = Rx.Observable.when(
    Rx.Observable.interval(250).and(Rx.Observable.of("A", "B", "C")).thenDo(selector),
    Rx.Observable.interval(300).and(Rx.Observable.of("a", "b")).thenDo(selector)
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

// => Next: 0, A 
// => Next: 0, a
// => Next: 1, B
// => Next: 1, b
// => Next: 2, C
// => Completed
```